# Why $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ does not mean the sum from $1$ to infinity is $-\frac{1}{12}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, infinity

Since $\zeta(-1)=\frac{1}{1^{-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{-1}}+\frac{1}{3^{-1}}+\cdots=-\frac{1}{12}$, why do we still say that $\sum^\infty_{n=1}n\rightarrow+\infty$?

Comment: Because $\zeta(-1)\ne\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$.

Comment: $\zeta(-1)$ is not $\frac{1}{1^{-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{-1}}+\cdots$. The equation $\zeta(s) = 1^{-s}+2^{-s}+\cdots$ is only valid for $Re(s)>1$.

Comment: You might find [this blog post I wrote once](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1551) about this question useful.

Comment: This question appears regularely and the "conclusion" seems to have an influence to the string theory. The tragedy : Mathematics is necessary to quantify physical results. But unfortunately, modern physics tries to interpret mathematical results (especially, if they are "beautiful") in a physical way. But Mathematics can, of course, not replace the understanding of physics.

Comment: This leads to tremendous problems, but instead of rethinking about this method, the problems turn into sensational physical "realities". This is especially the case in astronomics.

Comment: Note the linked question with 172 upvotes ! The discussion seems to result in the acceptance of the above equation because it can be derived from the extension of the riemann-zeto-function. I agree with Daniel Fischer, who calls this a "misused result".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, it is **NOT TRUE** that

$$\zeta(-1) = \frac{1}{1^{-1}} + \frac{1}{2^{-1}} + \dots$$

The Riemann Zeta function is only defined as

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$

**for values of $s$ for which the real part of $s$ is greater than one**.

For other values, we can calculate the analytic continuation of $\zeta$ to define the function on the entire complex plane, but that means that we are expanding the definition **beyond** what it originally was.

---

You need to understand where our definitions come from:

- First, we have infinite sequences.
- From infinite sequences, we construct infinite series, and we **define** when these series converge.
- Then, we take a very specific family of infinite series, and we construct a function that sums them.
- Then, we expand the definition of this function to other numbers.

Now, if we take a series and ask "does it converge", we cannot say "yes because Riemann's zeta says so". We have an **earlier** definition, and to answer convergence, we need to use *that* definition.

---

So, why does $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i$$

diverge? Simply. Take the original definition of convergence of series, and the answer becomes:

Because $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i$$

is defined as $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^N a_i$$

And the sequence in the case when $a_i = i$ diverges toward $\infty.$

Comment: +1 Upvoted to counter vandal (?) downvote.

Comment: I am the downvoter. This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @avid19 This perfectly answers the question of why the sum is $\infty$. I intentionally left out any mention of Ramanujan's summation and Riemann's zeta functions because they have nothing to do with the fact that the sum is $\infty.$

Comment: @5xum that isn't quite his/her question though.

Comment: An answer should use the phrase "analytic continuation".

Comment: @avid19 No. If the question was "Why is $\zeta(-1) = -\frac{1}{12}$" ten the answer should involve that phrase. Anyway, the question was changed, and I will now edit my answer.

Comment: I upvoted your answer after you addressed the source of confusion. Before it didn't address OP's confusion at all.

Comment: @avid19 I know. That was my intent. I wanted OP to clearly show, in his question, what he did wrong. I did not want to *assume* where his confusion came from. I hoped OP would change the question. And I think the original answer was incomplete, yes, but not completely wrong, as you say. But anyway, we don't agree, and this is the internet, so nothing surprising.

Comment: @5xum How can we possibly sleep tonight knowing some stranger on the internet might be *wrong*? :)

Comment: @avid19 Personally, I will sleep on mi right side covered on a blanket. How will you sleep?

Comment: @5xum Again with missing the point. :)